# how to group by an array in JavaScript / Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array as below

```
array1 = [{"month":"January","location":"CENTRAL","percentage":94},
{"month":"February","location":"CENTRAL","percentage":97},
{"month":"March","location":"CENTRAL","percentage":93},
{"month":"January","location":"NORTH","percentage":95},
{"month":"February","location":"NORTH","percentage":91},
{"month":"March","location":"NORTH","percentage":98}];
```

I want to format my array to look as below

```
array2= [{
    location: "CENTRAL",
    January: 94,
    February: 97,
    March: 93},
    {
    location: "NORTH",
    January: 95,
    February: 91,
    March: 98}];
```

I tried to use group by function as below

```
function groupBy(list, keyGetter) {
    const map = new Map();
    list.forEach((item) => {
        const key = keyGetter(item);
        if (!map.has(key)) {
            map.set(key, [item]);
        } else {
            map.get(key).push(item);
        }
    });
    return map;
}

const grouped = groupBy(array1, arr => arr.location);
console.log(grouped);
```

but I am not getting the same format. Any suggestions please what I am missing in my idea ? Thank you very much.

Comment: A `Map` is not an `Array`

Comment: Your function is too basic for what you're expecting I guess. You don't show how you expect to aggregate the month values. You also return the data mapped by location but you're expecting a simple array.

Comment: Order cannot be guaranteed in an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can indeed use a map keyed by location, but then with plain objects as values. The problem in your code is that you push items into an *array*, and don't turn the month values into properties of a singular object (per location).

So given a map with plain objects, iterate the input and inject the month properties into those plain objects, with corresponding percentage values, and then take the values of that map:

```js
const array1 = [{"month":"January","location":"CENTRAL","percentage":94},{"month":"February","location":"CENTRAL","percentage":97},{"month":"March","location":"CENTRAL","percentage":93},{"month":"January","location":"NORTH","percentage":95},{"month":"February","location":"NORTH","percentage":91},{"month":"March","location":"NORTH","percentage":98}];

const map = new Map(array1.map(({location}) => [location, { location }]));
array1.forEach(o => map.get(o.location)[o.month] = o.percentage);
const result = [...map.values()];

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a dynamic approach by handing over the group key, the keys for key and value for collecting.

Then add all key/value pairs to the object and later return the values of the map.

```js
function groupBy(list, group, key, value) {
    return Array.from(list
        .reduce((map, object) => map.set(object[group], Object.assign(
            map.get(object[group]) || { [group]: object[group] },
            { [object[key]]: object[value] }
        )), new Map)
        .values()
    );
}

var array = [{ month: "January", location: "CENTRAL", percentage: 94 }, { month: "February", location: "CENTRAL", percentage: 97 }, { month: "March", location: "CENTRAL", percentage: 93 }, { month: "January", location: "NORTH", percentage: 95 }, { month: "February", location: "NORTH", percentage: 91 }, { month: "March", location: "NORTH", percentage: 98 }],
    result = groupBy(array, 'location', 'month', 'percentage');

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative is using the function `reduce` to group by `location` and the function `Object.values` to extract the grouped objects.

```js
let array1 = [{"month":"January","location":"CENTRAL","percentage":94},{"month":"February","location":"CENTRAL","percentage":97},{"month":"March","location":"CENTRAL","percentage":93},{"month":"January","location":"NORTH","percentage":95},{"month":"February","location":"NORTH","percentage":91},{"month":"March","location":"NORTH","percentage":98}],
    groupBy = (array, keygetter) => {
      return Object.values(array1.reduce((a, {month, percentage, ...rest}) => {
        let key = keygetter(rest);
        (a[key] || (a[key] = {location: key}))[month] = percentage;
        return a;
      }, Object.create(null)));
    },
    result = groupBy(array1, (o) => o.location);
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to use `.filter()` and `.map()`

```js
var array1 = [{"month":"January","location":"CENTRAL","percentage":94},
{"month":"February","location":"CENTRAL","percentage":97},
{"month":"March","location":"CENTRAL","percentage":93},
{"month":"January","location":"NORTH","percentage":95},
{"month":"February","location":"NORTH","percentage":91},
{"month":"March","location":"NORTH","percentage":98}];

const groupBy = (arr, prop, propName1, propName2, propName3) => 
  Object.assign({[prop]:propName1}
  , ...arr.filter(({[prop]:p}) => p === propName1)
    .map(({[propName2]:m, [propName3]:p}) => ({[m]: p}))
  );

const locations = ["CENTRAL", "NORTH"];

let res = locations.map(prop => groupBy(array1, "location", prop, "month", "percentage"));

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you can't just rearrange the properties in an object. According to the [ECMAScript specifications](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf):

> An ECMAScript **object** is an `unordered` collection of **properties**

You can rearrange the properties using your function, but the order will not be guaranteed in the final object.

Comment: I know it looks like that's what they're doing but I doubt that's what they're seeking.

Comment: Sorry @ChiefTwoPencils, but yes, it's the only difference between their two arrays - the order of the properties in each object.

Comment: The object's props are actually different. For example, they have explicit month props in the second rather than a single month prop in the first.

Comment: Whoops, missed that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another example using reduce, pass the callback function and specify the key in it

```js
array1 = [{
    "month": "January",
    "location": "CENTRAL",
    "percentage": 94
  },
  {
    "month": "February",
    "location": "CENTRAL",
    "percentage": 97
  },
  {
    "month": "March",
    "location": "CENTRAL",
    "percentage": 93
  },
  {
    "month": "January",
    "location": "NORTH",
    "percentage": 95
  },
  {
    "month": "February",
    "location": "NORTH",
    "percentage": 91
  },
  {
    "month": "March",
    "location": "NORTH",
    "percentage": 98
  }
];


function groupBy(list, callback) {
  return list.reduce((acc, x) => {
    const key = callback(x);
    if (!acc[key]) {
      return {
        ...acc,
        [key]: [x]
      }
    }
    return {
      ...acc,
      [key]: [...acc[key], x]
    }

  }, {})
}

// callback function
function locationName(obj) {
  return obj.location
}


console.log('group by location name:', groupBy(array1, locationName));
```